# Property of a cryptographic function

Tags: cryptography

What property of a cryptographic function is described below?

B = F(A)
A = F(B)

Comment: Self-invertibility.

Answer (score 3):

$F$ is an involution. You don't want this property for a block cipher since the function doesn't look "random". On the other hand, a stream cipher works exactly that way, but then it's a bit misleading to think of it as a function $F$: the function is missing an important parameter, namely time.

Comment: your answer looks broken

Comment: That's quite probable; in what way?

Answer (score 1):

Most mechanical cipher machines use a reciprocal cipher, so the machine doesn't need a separate "encode mode" and "decode mode".
A reciprocal cipher is an involution.

- Cryptodox: [reciprocal cipher](http://cryptodox.com/Reciprocal_cipher)
- Wikipedia: [reciprocal cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_cipher)